# How to force csv library to preserve leading zeroes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am using the csv library to apply double quotes around all non-numeric values.
One of the columns in my source is the US postal code.

My source file looks like this.

```
CustomerId,CustomerName,Street ,City,State,Zip Code
513916,Indian Tribal Council,1487 S. RESERVATION ROAD,PORTERVILLE,CA,93257
1176103,Iberdrola USA,100 MAIN STREET,New Gloucester,ME,04260
```

Once I have applied the csv code on the file.

The file starts to look like this.

```
"CustomerId","CustomerName","Street ","City","State","Zip Code"
513916,"Tule River Indian Tribal Council","1487 S. RESERVATION ROAD","PORTERVILLE","CA",93257
1176103,"Iberdrola USA","100 MAIN STREET","New Gloucester","ME",4260
```

Here is the code, I am using:

```
with open('C:\\Temp\\inputfile.csv', 'rb') as f_input, \
    open('C:\\Temp\\outputfile.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

    for row_input in csv_input:
        row_output = []
        for col in row_input:
            try:
                row_output.append(int(col))
            except ValueError, e:
                row_output.append(col)
        csv_output.writerow(row_output)
```

Is there any fix to preserve the leading zeroes from the inputfile?

Comment: `csv` isn't dropping leading zeros. You are. Why are you calling `int`?

Comment: Also `except ValueError, e` isn't valid in Python 3, so you may not be running the Python version you think you are.

Comment: It is still treating those values as ints. Try writing the entire row. Iterating every col in row and appending does not help anyways unless you want to filter off some columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without iterating each column it emits the code perfectly. Tested on 2.7

```
import csv
with open('C:\\Temp\\inputfile.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    with open('C:\\Temp\\outputfile.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

        for row_input in csv_input:
            print(row_input)
            csv_output.writerow(row_input)
```

Comment: I just discovered something strange. Your code works if I change the encoding of my file to ANSI. If I keep the file as UTF8, it fails. Thx for your help!

Comment: There is another minor issue, all of the columns are getting enclosed by quotes. The first column CustomerId doesn't need to get enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the values to `int`s.

```
print(int("04260"))
>>> 4260
```

Just remove the `try/except` block.

```
with open('C:\\Temp\\inputfile.csv', 'rb') as f_input, \
    open('C:\\Temp\\outputfile.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

    for row_input in csv_input:
        row_output = []
        for col in row_input:
            row_output.append(col)
        csv_output.writerow(row_output)
```

Comment: I accidentally tagged this as python3, but it is python 2. Your code is doing the exact same thing that my code does.